# Out of memory exception in c# when drawing trains in picturebox

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, out-of-memory, picturebox

I am trying to create an application that shows the online trains in **`picturebox`**

So to implement this i create a `worker thread` to get the online train position .so i define the thread as you can see here :

```
private Thread workerThread = null;
private delegate void UpdateListBoxDelegate();
private UpdateListBoxDelegate UpdateListBox = null;
```

In `Form_load` i call these:

```
            UpdateListBox = new UpdateListBoxDelegate(this.UpdateStatus);
            // Initialise and start worker thread
            workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.GetOnlineTrain));
            workerThread.Start();
```

My method that delegate handles that is :

```
private void UpdateStatus()
{
    foreach (TimeTable onlineTrain in OnlineTrainList.ToList())
    {
        if (lstSensorLeft.Count != 0 || lstSensorRight.Count != 0)
        {
            pictureBoxonlineTrain.Image = null;

            DrawOnlineTrain();
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBoxonlineTrain.Image = null;
        }
    }

    this.Invalidate();
}
```

The `GetOnlineTrain` get the position of online train as you can see here :

```
public void GetOnlineTrain()
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            TimeTableRepository objTimeTableREpository = new TimeTableRepository();
            OnlineTrainList = objTimeTableREpository.GetAll().ToList();
            objTimeTableREpository = null;
            Invoke(UpdateListBox);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception a)
    {
    }

}
```

And the final function draws the online trains on the `picturebox` :

```
   public void DrawOnlineTrain()
        {
            Bitmap map=null;
            if (OnlineTrainList.Count > 0)
            {
                map = new Bitmap(pictureBoxonlineTrain.Size.Width, pictureBoxonlineTrain.Size.Height);

                var graph = Graphics.FromImage(map);

                foreach (TimeTable t in OnlineTrainList.ToList())
                {
                   // graph.Dispose();
                    Rectangle rectTrainState = new Rectangle(t.XTrainLocation.Value - 3,
                                                             t.YTrainLocation.Value - 3,
                                                             15, 15);
                    graph.FillRectangle(RedBrush, rectTrainState);
                    graph.DrawString(t.TrainId.ToString(), pictureBoxonlineTrain.Font, Brushes.White, t.XTrainLocation.Value  -3, t.YTrainLocation.Value -3);

                }
            }
            pictureBoxonlineTrain.Image = map;
          //  pictureBoxonlineTrain.Image.Save(@"C:\RailwayShiraz\ShirazMetro\ShirazRailWayWeb\Images\Train.jpg");
        }
```

but my application spends a lot of memory and sometimes i got the `Out of memory exception` and sometimes my trains `Disappears` from the `picturebox`. To draw online train first time i draw the map of trains (lines ,stations ,...)  on `picturebox` with size `x=A` and `y=b` after that i create another `picturebox` with the same size and put the second `picturebox` on first `picturebox` using this code:

```
    pictureBoxonlineTrain.Parent = pictureBoxMetroMap;
```

I think maybe some part of my code consumes a lot of memory and i should use `Dispose` or something else .Sometime i got `out of memory exception` and the error is caused by `graphic` i am not sure !And sometimes i got the error from this line :

```
   map = new Bitmap(pictureBoxonlineTrain.Size.Width, pictureBoxonlineTrain.Size.Height);
```

Could you please give me some help .is there any class that i should dispose that?or the problem is caused by my implementation

I trace the memory usage from `taskmanager` and some times my usage reach to `1,666,881` and my application exits.

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dispose bitmaps which you no longer need. They consume huge amounts of unmanaged memory. The GC is not aware of unmanaged memory and cannot trigger a collection based on unreachable unmanaged memory.

Comment: Thank you which part of code i should dispose the bitmap ?

Comment: Do it as soon as you know the bitmap is no longer used but not before.

Comment: i my code i use this :pictureBoxonlineTrain.Image = null; can i change it to pictureBoxonlineTrain.Image.Dispose();?

Comment: First, assign null to Image or else you'll have a disposed image configured. Who knows what that even does.

Comment: Wrap both `map` and `graph` in `using` blocks. They're both disposable.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge how can i do that

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge could you please give me an example and in which part of code i should use that?

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge i asked this question here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592729/bitmap-and-picturebox-cause-out-of-memory-exception